# InvalidRegistration on sending push to iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I had a problem. I try to send notification to iOS app with sending post request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Request:

```
{
    "notification":
        {
            "body": "test",
            "sound" : "default",
        },
        "data":
        {
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
        },
    "project_id": "my-app-id",
    "registration_ids": [ "6d0a9931d0b5145e69c2aa5402b4acbf46b6da7193c659c5858ff4c3baa417d5" ],
    "time_to_live" : 3,
    "priority" : "high"
  }
```

and every time I get 
responce:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6755836923824168435,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I use NWPusher (https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) everything is Ok, I get the push notification
[image of success sending push notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DAYm.jpg)

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code for how you are generating the Firebase ID Token that you're passing as the registration ID? Also, are you able to receive notifications sent from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification)?

Comment: I found issue. The problem was that previous developer did not push last commit to git. In my case I tried to send APNS token to fire base instead fire base token.